# GIT error while building my project

Tags: git

we are using GIT as repository and while build project from jenkins , i am getting this error.

03:22:56    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)

03:22:56 **Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git config remote.origin.url ssh://cibuild@atlgit-01.us.manh.com:7999/HHHH/HH.git" returned status code 4:**

03:22:56 stdout: 
03:22:56 **stderr: error: failed to write new configuration file .git/config.lock**

03:22:56 
03:22:56    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1435)
03:22:56    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1411)